# How to retrieve highlighted sequences of an .epub file in Python?

Tags: python, highlight, epub

I'm used to highlight the important parts of the .epub books I read on my Kobo reader, and I'd like to write a script extracting these highlighted parts, and saving them in a .txt file.

I've checked out [epub library documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/epub/), but I couldn't find anything relevant to my problem.

Can anyone give me some tips on how to select and save the highlighted parts of my epub files? Is there a specific tag I should search in the file?

Comment: Have you tried fiddling with the object returned when opening the file? For example, see what `book.opf.manifest` is made up of.

Answer (score 0):

The highlights and the annotations are stored in the KoboReader.sqlite file, not in each EPUB file.

You might want to check my script out:

http://github.com/pettarin/export-kobo

or search for Calibre plugins (there are several ones that can export highlights/annotations).